# Run dynamically added tasks one after one

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

Application (wpf, .net framework 4.8) can receive some commands from outside (rpc, ui, etc) and can be received faster than can be executed. While commands work with hardware, I want them to be executed one by one.
I search for ideas, bc I do not even sure than my plan will work.

Me current idea is to somehow use `ActionBlock` from Dataflow, but I can't figure out how to properly write it.

Something like this.

```
        class Foo
        {
            ActionBlock<Task> runner;
            int index = 0;

            public async void TestTask(int index)
            {
                await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(1000, 10000));
                Debug.WriteLine("Task completed " + index);
            }

            public Foo()
            {
                runner = new ActionBlock<Task>(task =>
                {
                    task();
                });
            }

            private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                // should post TestTask(intex) for delayed execution 
                runner.Post(???);
                index++;
            }
        }
```

May be there are better ways to achieve this functionality or some clever architecture to miss this problems?

Comment: Why is the `TestTask` `async void` instead of `async Task`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias mostly because this is semi-synthetic code for demonstration of problem

Comment: ConcurrentQueue, consume from it and execute with awaiting.

Comment: @Ryan as I understand, `ConcurrentQueue` is just a container, and not provide any functionality to execute then, so I need to implement additional logic to retrieve tasks from it and run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler approach is to just pass in an asynchronous delegate type, i.e., `Func<Task>`, and use closures to create the delegate instances:

```
ActionBlock<Func<Task>> runner;

public async Task TestTask(int index)
{
  await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(1000, 10000));
  Debug.WriteLine("Task completed " + index);
}

public Foo()
{
  runner = new ActionBlock<Func<Task>>(async func =>
  {
    await func();
  });
}

private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var indexValue = index++;
  runner.Post(() => TestTask(indexValue));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Managed to achieve what I expect.
Mostly my original idea was right, only minor fixes was needed.
Here they are:

- `ActionBlock` should accept tuple of deletage and parameters
- `ActionBlock`'s actoin should be async and await for task

Minimal code to show my final result:

```
class Foo
{
    delegate Task TaskDelegate(int book);
    ActionBlock<Tuple<TaskDelegate, int>> runner;
    int index = 0;

    public async Task TestTask(int index)
    {
        await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(1000, 10000));
        Debug.WriteLine("Task completed " + index);
    }

    public Foo()
    {
        runner = new ActionBlock<Tuple<TaskDelegate, int>>(async task =>
        {
            await task.Item1(task.Item2);
        });
    }

    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        runner.Post(Tuple.Create<TaskDelegate, int>(TestTask, index));
        index++;
    }
}
```